# Explanation of Libido in anime

Tags: tropes, star-driver, captain-earth

Seems like libido is the energy source for mechas in various series such as Star Driver, and Captain Earth. Exactly what is this libido it speaks of? Lust? Why is it that the world will supposedly end if something consumes all libido?

Comment: Good question, I found it odd too

Comment: Don't forget Gantz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In simple terms, libido is another word used to describe life force, or orgone energy. You can think of it like mana.

> Orgone energy is a hypothetical universal life force originally proposed in the 1930s by Wilhelm Reich. -[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orgone)

To answer your second question (paraphrasing from the source article):
Libido generates orgone energy, so:

No libido -> no orgone energy -> no life.

Answer (score 0):

However the real definition for libido is "sexual desire" which most anime refer to when mentioning the term. So yes lust, so the anime is probably referencing sexual desire or libido as power for their machines.

Comment: See, that's what I don't get, how does lust power up anything? :|

Comment: It's anime. For all we know, lust could be generating chi, mana, chakra or something...

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat The literal meaning of libido is the desire for sexual activity or lust. However, in the context of captain earth, who explicitly state that its orgone energy that powers the mechs, its much more likely IMO that the anime writers wanted some cool term to use, and the orgone libido relationship fit the bill.